# py.test cyclomatic complexity plugin

Tags: python, unit-testing, complexity-theory, pytest

Does anyone know if there is a [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) plugin for py.test?

Comment: Unit testing is dynamic: executing specific code paths. Cyclomatic complexity is a feature of static analysis. I use tools to do both in Python every day, but they're totally unrelated. What is that you would like a cyclomatic complexity plugin for py.test to do?

Comment: Because it is easier to refactor things early rather than later.  Running two tools requires two steps -- Yes, I am lazy ^_~